# Is this a current patent: CA2277698A1

Tags: expired-patent

My question is CA2277698A1 a patent or only a application for a patent?

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, it i[s a patent application](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/CA_2277698_A1), not a granted patent.  The persistent identifier is:   lens.org/134-360-901-561-277.

Checking in its legal status, [it is dead](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/CA_2277698_A1/regulatory).